# lldb type summary not work for sub-object

Tags: python, types, lldb, summary

I have written a python script to provide summary function for a class, and it work fine for inspecting the instance directly.

```
def init(debugger):
    debugger.HandleCommand("type summary add -F pix_lldb.pix_lldb_summary.show_bxstr bxstr")

def show_bxstr(value, internal_dict):
    addr = value.GetChildMemberWithName("m_first").GetValueAsUnsigned()
    frame = value.frame
    e = lldb.SBError()
    str = frame.GetThread().GetProcess().ReadCStringFromMemory(addr, 0xffffff, e)
    return ("[{1}]{0}").format(str, len(str))
```

[image]

but when I expand other object which contains instance of the class, it will just be shown regularly.
[image]

so how to make it shown correctly as the standalone one?

Comment: If I'm understanding your example correctly, it looks like your summary provider is getting called in both cases.  That's what's printing the [0] at the end of the first line in your second example.  It looks like for some reason in the second case your summary is getting an empty string.  You don't check for errors at any stage, so it's hard to see where this went wrong, however.

Comment: BTW, you can debug these formatters.  Just put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the beginning of the formatter, then do something that will trigger its use, and you will stop in the lldb console with the `(Pdb)` prompt, and you can step through the formatter operation.  That will both tell you whether the formatter was actually triggered (though it looks like in this case it was) and allow you to step through it to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: thanks @JimIngham !  if I put `pdb.set_trace()` in my code, the debugger hangs,  the lldb console won't respond to any input.

Comment: Ack, sorry about that.  Xcode has some problems with the Python interpreter loop.  If you can do this in command-line lldb (maybe just write a command-line app to test just this type and formatter) you should have more luck.